# django admin overriding save method at inlines?

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to override the save method for inlines form and parent at the same time?

I would like to change the value of a field when the user saves the edited inline form.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

To customize the saving of inlines, you can override the FormSet

```
class SomeInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def save_new(self, form, commit=True):
        return super(SomeInlineFormSet, self).save_new(form, commit=commit)

    def save_existing(self, form, instance, commit=True):
        return form.save(commit=commit)

class SomeInline(admin.StackedInline):
    formset = SomeInlineFormSet
    # ....
```

Note that the `save_new()` only uses the form to get the data, it does not let the `ModelForm` commit the data. Instead, it constructs the model itself. This allows it to insert the parent relation since they don't exist in the form. That's why overriding `form.save()` does not work.

In the case of generic inlines, the `form.save()` method is never called, and `form.cleaned_data` is used instead to get all values, and `Field.save_form_data()` is used to store the values in the model instance.

---

FYI, some general tip to figure these kind of things out; it's really valuable to have an IDE (or maybe vim config or Sublime setup) that allows to jump to symbol definitions really easily. The code above was figured out by jumping into the inline/formset code, and see what is happening. In the case of PyCharm, that works by holding Command (or Ctrl), and clicking on the symbol. If you're a vim user, `ctags` might be able to do a similar thing for you.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to hook into your inline model's `pre_save' signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from your_app.models import YourModel

def callback(sender, **kwargs):
    # 'instance' is the model instance that is about to be saved,
    # so you can do whatever you want to it.
    instance.field = new_value

pre_save.connect(callback, sender=YourModel)
```

But I'm not sure why you can't just override the `save` method, which is almost always a better approach.

Comment: +1 For pointing out that is better to override `save()` method on the Model!